# Spinner value gets automatically updated to position 0 which takes data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I am facing a problem in my android app.I have a spinner which takes data(latitude and longitude) from the Firebase. When clicked on the another option spinner takes that value but then after some time it automatically updates to position 0 and takes the value of position 0.

Here is my code..

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                    list.clear();
                                                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                        list.add(child.getKey());
                                                    }
                                                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MapsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                                                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                                                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                                                            node = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                                            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(node);
                                                            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                                    latitude = (double) dataSnapshot.child("latitude/location").getValue();
                                                                    longitude = (double) dataSnapshot.child("longitude/location").getValue();
                                                                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);


                                                                }


                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                                    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
                                                                }
                                                            });

                                                        }


                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                                                        }
                                                    });
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()`.

Hope it helps you.